# Jquery Split-able Table Cell similar like div splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working on asp mvc . I have a table on form now  i want to make some of my table-cell splittable for saving space.

How can i make it splittable just like splittable div that we can see by clicking this link
 http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using the jquery plugin you link to yourself?

Comment: @aaberg these plugins work only for div not for td elements, so i need to apply it for td element .